# Magento 2.2.3 Internal Server Error: Read timed out after 10 seconds

Tags: magento2, php, error, zend-framework, timeout

I have a magento 2.2.3 shop that is throwing me an internal server error every time I try to edit or create a new product. When I click save, it loads for about 10 seconds this shows internal server error. Try again later. I checked the system.log file and it shows the following error:

```
[2018-04-09 21:36:38] main.CRITICAL: Read timed out after 10 seconds  {"method":"POST","url":"https://custombuttons97.com/admin_cfytnh/catalog/product/save/id/5/type/simple/store/0/set/12/key/923d4f492fbf22029126adee53137102bd09deee49d3bdb1f83885e9ca3c4853/back/edit","invalidateInfo":{"server":"[object] (Zend\\Uri\\Uri: http://127.0.0.1:6082/)","tagsPattern":"((^|,)cat_p_5(,|$))"}} []
```

What would cause this issue and how can I fix it?

UPDATE:

I modified the file vendor/magento/module-cache-invalidate/Model/PurgeCache.php I changed the timeout to 90 seconds and I am now getting an error of timed out after 90 seconds. See below:

```
[2018-04-10 18:45:11] main.CRITICAL: Read timed out after 90 seconds {"method":"POST","url":"https://custombuttons97.com/admin_cfytnh/catalog/product/save/id/5/type/simple/store/0/set/12/key/8937840148454054d5ff7ae2ff947a60b2b477567a535f0c1b649b69c06bdc23/back/edit","invalidateInfo":{"server":"[object] (Zend\\Uri\\Uri: http://127.0.0.1:6082/)","tagsPattern":"((^|,)cat_p_5(,|$))"}} []
[2018-04-10 18:45:18] main.CRITICAL: A valid response status line was not found in the provided string {"method":"POST","url":"https://custombuttons97.com/admin_cfytnh/catalog/product/save/id/5/type/simple/store/0/set/12/key/8937840148454054d5ff7ae2ff947a60b2b477567a535f0c1b649b69c06bdc23/back/edit","invalidateInfo":{"server":"[object] (Zend\\Uri\\Uri: http://127.0.0.1:6082/)","tagsPattern":"((^|,)cat_p_5(,|$))"}} []
[2018-04-10 18:45:22] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'product.reviews' element cannot be added as child to 'product_tabs', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
```

Comment: Seem that you were using the curl to work with API. Your issue relates to the timeout issue. Try to increase the timeout for your curl. This will solve your timeout issue. The default timeout PHP is 13 seconds.

Comment: I'm not using the API. The site is running varnish cache, so I'm thinking somehow that is involved.

Comment: Possibly a Zend timeout issue? I changed the value in the Client.php file for timeout from 10 to 90 and saw no difference.

Comment: @Kazpilot25, you got solution?

Answer (score 0):

Cache problem.
Maybe you are using varnish cache, please check the concurrent connection setting or try to restart Varnish.

Comment: I think you're on the right track. The site is running varnish cache, and the log shows 3 attempts 5 seconds apart, which is a varnish setting for attempts. Now if I could just figure out what exactly is going on. I've restarted varnish with no luck. How do I check the concurrent connection setting?

Comment: Scratch that... It shows 2 attempts 10 seconds apart.

Comment: I ran varnishlog and there are no errors thrown in varnish when the internal server error occurs. I'm starting to think it's a Zend timeout somehow.